# cant figure out how to get the return showing .toFixed(2) amount without error

Tags: javascript, html

The script works great for adding items on invoice however i cant figure how to convert the data using .toFixed(2) to show $10.00  instead of 10. I get an error every time I try to add .toFixed(2) . thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var answer = document.getElementById('total');

    var x = document.getElementById('itemprice1');
    var y = document.getElementById('itemprice2');
    var z = document.getElementById('itemprice3');
    var w = document.getElementById('itemprice4');
    var taxt = document.getElementById('taxtot');
    var thetot = document.getElementById('thetot');

    // parseFloat converts to values, otherwise you'll concatenate the strings.
    answer.value = parseFloat("0" + x.value) + parseFloat("0" + y.value) + parseFloat("0" + z.value) + parseFloat("0" + w.value);

}

function myFunction1() {
  var answer = document.getElementById('total');
    var taxt = document.getElementById('taxtot');
   var thetot = document.getElementById('thetot');

   thetot.value = parseFloat("0" + answer.value) + parseFloat("0" + taxt.value);
  if (thetot > "0") {


  {
    //function myFunction2() 
    var taxt = document.getElementById('taxtot');
    var tx1 = document.getElementById('tax1');
    var tx2 = document.getElementById('tax2');
     var tx3 = document.getElementById('tax3');
    var tx4 = document.getElementById('tax4');
    var x = document.getElementById('itemprice1');
    var y = document.getElementById('itemprice2');
    var z = document.getElementById('itemprice3');
    var w = document.getElementById('itemprice4');
    var answer = document.getElementById('total');



    taxt.value = parseFloat("0" + tx1.value) * ("0" + x.value) + parseFloat("0" + tx2.value) * ("0" + y.value) + parseFloat("0" + tx3.value) * ("0" + z.value) + parseFloat("0" + tx4.value) * ("0" + w.value);
  }
 }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Expressions like `parseFloat("0" + x.value)` can be simply `+x.value`, concatenating a leading zero is pointless.

Comment: Where do you use toFixed? you also should get rid of the extra }

Comment: @robg the zero is needed to not show an error on the page while waiting for an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your controls are in a form, so you can reference them simply using their name in the form. You can also convert strings to numbers using unary `+`:

```
function myFunction(formId) {
    var f = document.getElementById(formId);
    var answer =  f.total;
    var x = +f.itemprice1.value;
    var y = +f.itemprice2.value;
    var z = +f.itemprice3.value;
    var w = +f.itemprice4.value;
    var taxt = f.taxtot;
    var thetot = f.thetot;

    // Presumably here is where you want to use toFixed
    answer.value = '$' + (x + y + z + w).toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function to_dollar_string(amount)
{
    return "$" + amount.toFixed(2);
}

to_dollar_string(10);
=> "$10.00"
to_dollar_string(10.567);
=> "$10.57"
```